# "work as a journalist on/at a magazine"

Tags: prepositions

Could you please tell me why and when people use "on a magazine"? I thought it should be *at* but it seemed that many people use *on*.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

*Work at* or *work for* generally indicates the relationship between the person and the employer.

*Work on* is more about the relationship between the person and the work.

> *I'm working on* [the latest issue of] *a magazine* means to be actively involved in the process of producing something.
>
> Boss: "Have you written the article yet?" Journalist: "I'm working on it."
>
> I'm working on a book (I have an idea for a book and I'm writing
>   material for it).
>
> I'm working on my backhand (in tennis, I'm regularly practising to try to improve this
>   particular stroke).
>
> I'm working on my brother (I need some help with a job and I'm trying to
>   persuade my brother to do it).

Compare this with:

> I work for The Times (The Times employs me).
>
> I work at The Times [office] (I go to The Times office every day).

This is not a hard and fast rule but I hope it helps with some of the subtleties of why people might choose to use on/at/for.

Answer (score -1):

Working on a magazine is like working on a book or working on a new deck.

Working at a magazine is like working at a newspaper or working at a tavern.

Comment: In the UK, we can say that a journalist worked **on** 'The Times' for five years meaning that the journalist was employed by the newspapaper.

Comment: @BarrieEngland As you probably are aware, that does not happen on this side of the Atlantic.

Comment: Not even 'He was on the Wall Street Journal' for five years'?

Comment: @Barrie: I think that would be readily understandable, but I doubt many people over here would word it that way (as opposed to say, _was at_ or _worked for_).